# how to find null pointer exception with logcat

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a small app that takes a data file in external storage and emails it. I keep getting 'null pointer exceptions' right away in logcat and then my app dies. I can't seem to locate my exception and I am wondering if there is a way to determine the line of code that is causing this. I have the MainActivity class and then a class called SendData- the code is below. I'm new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated- thank you.

```
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity_ErrorLog";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Create the getData intent
    Intent intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class); 

    public void onStart()
    {
        {       
        try 
        {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) 
            {
        // verify the paths
                String currentDBPath = "TLC_COMMON/database.db";
                String backupDBPath = "database.db"; 
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) 
                {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();                    
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)     
        {   
            // change the V below to E when complete
            Log.v(TAG,"ERROR: Database file not created"); 
        }
        startActivity(intentgetData);
        }

    }

  }
```

--new class

public class SendData extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

```
/* Checks if external storage is available to read */   
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() 
    {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
        {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

/** Called when the user clicks the Send My Data button */
public SendData(View view) 
    {

    // Send data by email
        {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    // verify it is saving as this file name; also path in previous class
            String fileName = "database.db"; 
            if (root.canWrite()) 
                { 
                File attachment = new File(root, fileName); 
                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);                
                email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Exercise data");
                email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
                // is the Uri necessary?
                email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
                // look at this VVV
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send the data via Email"));} 
            else 
                {
                // Change the V below to E when complete
                Log.v(TAG, "Email send failed");
                }
            }
        }
public void finish() 
{   
}

}
```

```
11-13 13:29:37.343: W/dalvikvm(3319): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418e3300)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.va.datasender/com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: +1.  You might have no idea how refreshing it is to see someone ask this question.  I've lost count (actually, not so sad as to have counted in the first place) of the number of questions on here where someone says NPE and posts the logcat. First comment says "what line is 74?" (or whatever the trace says), and you are the first to ask, and in advance, "how do you know?"  Made me smile.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know if you use Eclipse, and I don't know if Eclipse has this feature, but in Intellij IDEA, each line in the logcat which refers to a line in your code is a hyperlink.  Just click it an it takes you straight to the line in the editor.  Nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the lowest "Caused by" and continue down until you reach a line from your code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
     at com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
```

The `<init>` means you are doing something as a class variable or inside a constructor before the Activity has a valid Context... But the specific problem is on line 36.

I would guess that you are trying to create an Intent with `this`. Initialize your Intent inside `onCreate()` instead.

---

Found it. Change this:

```
// Create the getData intent
Intent intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class);
```

to:

```
Intent intentgetData;
```

and inside `onCreate()` (or `onStart()` just before calling `startActivity()`) add:

```
intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from line 36 on your MainActivity. Check there for the problem.

```
11-13 13:29:37.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3319):     at com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exeption from line number 36: `at com.example.va.datasender.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error log also shows `android.content.Intent.<init>` after the `MainActivity.java:36`, I would check the value for the first parameter in the following line, when instantiating `intentgetData`:

```
Intent intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class);
```

Instead of having the instatiation done there, try doing it in the `onStart()` method just before calling `startActivity(intentgetData);`:

```
Intent intentgetData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendData.class); 
startActivity(intentgetData);
```